# Insert into database using excel from database start from col 2

Tags: php, excel, database

I`m trying to insert data into a database, from an excel file but starting from column 2 because the first column is being used for the name of the row in the table.

This is my form to input the file, this code reads from the first column, I want to start reading from column 2.

```
<h2>Import Excel File into MySQL Database using PHP</h2>
    <div class="outer-container">
        <form action="import.php" method="post"
            name="frmExcelImport" id="frmExcelImport" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div>
                <label>Choose Excel
                    File</label> <input type="file" name="file"
                    id="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx">
                <button type="submit" id="submit" name="import"
                    class="btn-submit">Import</button>

            </div>

        </form>

    </div>
    <div id="response" class="<?php if(!empty($type)) { echo $type . " display-block"; } ?>"><?php if(!empty($message)) { echo $message; } ?></div>
```

and this is the action file:

```
<?php
include 'koneksi/koneksi.php';
require_once('vendor/php-excel-reader/excel_reader2.php');
require_once('vendor/SpreadsheetReader.php');

if (isset($_POST["import"]))
{

  $allowedFileType = ['application/vnd.ms-excel','text/xls','text/xlsx','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'];

  if(in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"],$allowedFileType)){

        $targetPath = 'uploads/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetPath);

        $Reader = new SpreadsheetReader($targetPath);

        $sheetCount = count($Reader->sheets());

        for($i=0;$i<$sheetCount;$i++)
        {
            $Reader->ChangeSheet($i);

            foreach ($Reader as $Row )
            {

                $id_koperasi = "";
                if(isset($Row[0])) {
                    $id_koperasi = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[0]);
                }

                $nama_koperasi = "";
                if(isset($Row[1])) {
                    $nama_koperasi = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[1]);
                }

                $alamat = "";
                if(isset($Row[2])) {
                    $alamat = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[2]);
                }

                $telp = "";
                if(isset($Row[3])) {
                    $telp = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[3]);
                }

                $hp = "";
                if(isset($Row[4])) {
                    $hp = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[4]);
                }

                $nama_cp = "";
                if(isset($Row[5])) {
                    $nama_cp = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[5]);
                }

                $email = "";
                if(isset($Row[6])) {
                    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[6]);
                }

                $tanggal_fu = "";
                if(isset($Row[7])) {
                    $tanggal_fu = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[7]);
                }

                $ket_fu = "";
                if(isset($Row[8])) {
                    $ket_fu = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[8]);
                }

                $hasil_pembahasan = "";
                if(isset($Row[9])) {
                    $hasil_pembahasan = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[9]);
                }

                $status = "";
                if(isset($Row[10])) {
                    $status = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[10]);
                }

                $provinsi = "";
                if(isset($Row[11])) {
                    $provinsi = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[11]);
                }

                $kota = "";
                if(isset($Row[12])) {
                    $kota = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[12]);
                }

                $kec = "";
                if(isset($Row[13])) {
                    $kec = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[13]);
                }

                $kel = "";
                if(isset($Row[14])) {
                    $kel = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[14]);
                }

                $rt = "";
                if(isset($Row[15])) {
                    $rt = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[15]);
                }

                $rw = "";
                if(isset($Row[16])) {
                    $rw = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[16]);
                }

                $jln = "";
                if(isset($Row[17])) {
                    $jln = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[17]);
                }

                $kodep = "";
                if(isset($Row[18])) {
                    $kodep = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[18]);
                }

                if (!empty($id_koperasi) || !empty($nama_koperasi) || !empty($alamat) || !empty($telp) || !empty($hp) || !empty($nama_cp) || !empty($email) || !empty($tanggal_fu) || !empty($ket_fu) || !empty($hasil_pembahasan) || !empty($status) || !empty($provinsi) || !empty($kota) || !empty($kec) || !empty($kel) || !empty($rt) || !empty($rw) || !empty($jln) || !empty($kodep) ) {
                    $query = "INSERT INTO t_koperasi(id,id_koperasi,nama_koperasi,alamat,telp,hp,nama_cp,email,tanggal_fu,ket_fu,hasil_pembahasan,status,provinsi,kota,kec,kel,rt,rw,jln,kodep) VALUES ('',
        '$id_koperasi',
        '$nama_koperasi',
        '$alamat',
        '$telp',
        '$hp',
        '$nama_cp',
        '$email',
        '$tanggal_fu',
        '$ket_fu',
        '$hasil_pembahasan',
        '$status',
        '$provinsi',
        '$kota',
        '$kec',
        '$kel',
        '$rt',
        '$rw',
        '$jln',
        '$kodep')" or die(mysqli_error($con));
    ;
                    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

                    if (! empty($result)) {
                        $type = "success";
                        $message = "SUKSES";
                    } else {
                        $type = "error";
                        $message = "Problem in Importing Excel Data";

                    }
                }
             }

         }
  }
  else
  { 
        $type = "error";
        $message = "Invalid File Type. Upload Excel File.";
  }
}

include 'views/v_import.php'
?>
```

I already tried to put $col = 1 but it still wont work, I tried using the `for=i`  but it still will not work.

Answer (score 0):

a possible solution with an extra counter

```
        $Reader->ChangeSheet($i);
        $number = 0;
        foreach ($Reader as $Row )
        {
            if ($number!=0) {
               ......
            }
            $number++;
        }
```